# Workflow 2013 with one server topology socket connection error

Tags: 2013, workflow

**Getting this error when using workflow 2013**

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 6/1/2023 4:07 AM. Details of last request: HTTP  to [https://intranet.com/sandbox/_api/web/lists(guid'd64761af-6fb5-41a2-985e-1529c3c13568')](https://intranet.com/sandbox/_api/web/lists(guid%27d64761af-6fb5-41a2-985e-1529c3c13568%27)) Correlation Id:  Instance Id: 6b4b0818-684c-49b0-9e47-22dfbe45441f

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, IAsyncResult result)
Retry now

All services are running correctly no issue while installing. Performed a health check https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/